# runtime error when i assign HashMap<String, String> map; to holder .Click to see more information

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap, runtime-error

On this activity i want to show data from SQLite to Listview but it's still runTime error. Can you check this logcat error to tell me what happened and how i can do please ?

this is my logcat : i can get data from SQLite now

```
08-22 12:27:11.911: W/KeyCharacterMap(481): No keyboard for id 0
08-22 12:27:11.911: W/KeyCharacterMap(481): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_nickname(481): holly
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_fname(481): Yuma
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_lname(481): sama
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_nickname(481): mao
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_fname(481): ho
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_lname(481): koj
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_nickname(481): YYY
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_fname(481): GGG
08-22 12:27:29.571: I/item_lname(481): UUU
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_nickname(481): DDD
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_fname(481): HHH
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_lname(481): TTT
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_nickname(481): RICKY
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_fname(481): SAMA
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_lname(481): SUZA
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_nickname(481): LLLL
08-22 12:27:29.581: I/item_fname(481): bbb
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_lname(481): MMM
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_nickname(481): XXX
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_fname(481): VVV
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_lname(481): CCC
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_nickname(481): UUU
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_fname(481): LLL
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_lname(481): PPP
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_nickname(481): lang
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_fname(481): rong
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_lname(481): lang
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_nickname(481): white
08-22 12:27:29.591: I/item_fname(481): sim
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_lname(481): same
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_nickname(481): NONG
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_fname(481): Bome
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_lname(481): NING
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_nickname(481): JAN
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_fname(481): Ball
08-22 12:27:29.601: I/item_lname(481): JON
08-22 12:27:29.611: D/AndroidRuntime(481): Shutting down VM
08-22 12:27:29.611: W/dalvikvm(481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlite/com.example.sqlite.FriendsListActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.example.sqlite.FriendsListActivity.showAllList(FriendsListActivity.java:56)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at com.example.sqlite.FriendsListActivity.onCreate(FriendsListActivity.java:41)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-22 12:27:29.631: E/AndroidRuntime(481):  ... 11 more
```

This is my code FriendsListActivity

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.sqlite.db.FriendsDB;
import com.example.sqlite.entry.FriendEntry;

public class FriendsListActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;
private FriendsDB db;
private SimpleAdapter sAdap;
private ArrayList<FriendEntry> friends;
private TextView hellotext;
private ListView hellolistview;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.friendlist_layout); 
    context = this;
    db = new FriendsDB(context);
    friends = new ArrayList<FriendEntry>();

    showAllList();
}
public void showAllList(){
    //view matching
    hellotext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hellotext);
    hellolistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hellolistview);
    //select data
    friends = db.selectAll();
        if(friends.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(context,"You dont have any friend.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            for (int i = 0;i<=friends.size();i++){
            // set value for friends    
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("item_nickname", friends.get(i).getNickname());
                map.put("item_fname", friends.get(i).getFname());
                map.put("item_lname", friends.get(i).getLname());

                Log.i("item_nickname", friends.get(i).getNickname());
                Log.i("item_fname", friends.get(i).getFname());
                Log.i("item_lname", friends.get(i).getLname());
            }

            //adapter   
            hellolistview.setAdapter(new adapter());
        }
    }


private class adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Holder holder;
    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return friends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        //create
        if( view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.nickname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_nickname);
            holder.fname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_fname);
            holder.lname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_lname);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        //assign 
        holder.nickname.setText(map.get("item_nickname"));
        holder.fname.setText(map.get("item_fname"));
        holder.lname.setText(map.get("item_lname"));


        return view;
    }

    private class Holder{

        public TextView nickname;
        public TextView fname;
        public TextView lname;
    }
}


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the for loop code

```
for (int i = 1;i<=friends.size();i++){
```

to

```
for (int i = 0;i<friends.size();i++){
```

---

*Array position starts from 0 (not from 1). In your case log says that size of list is 11. So loop should read elements of array from 0 to 10 (not from 1 to 11).*

---

After update of question:-

Again you did a mistake

`for (int i = 0;i<=friends.size();i++){` You should not use `<=` only use `<` so replace for loop as

```
 for (int i = 0;i<friends.size();i++)
```

Comment: Thank you .But it's still error please check MyeditQuetion agian

Comment: Your edited question is `for (int i = 0;i<=friends.size();i++){` again you have did a mistake. change that with `for (int i = 0;i<friends.size();i++){`

Comment: Check my updated answer. And see what did you do mistake. Simply replace the for loop which I have given.

Comment: NOW it not have error now. But why listview is show only last value 20 list for example: now i insert nickname=AAA,fname=BBB,lname=CCC to database and In my database have nickname=AAA,fname=BBB,lname=CCC()and nickname=DDD,fname=FFF,lname=EEE  for now .in listview output is
AAA BBB CCC 20list
but i want it to show like this 
firstlist(AAA BBB CCC)
        secondlist(DDD FFF EEE) 

Can you tell how to do like this output

Comment: Add map into new list and use that list into adapter. actually you are creating new map into loop evrytime. So at last you have only one map. You should add those map into list and use them into adpater.

Comment: MyArrList.add(map); like this

Comment: Yes same. And use this list into adapter.

Comment: Like this ==
holder.nickname.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("item_nickname"));
   holder.fname.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("item_fname"));
   holder.lname.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("item_lname"));

Comment: Yes perfect. Code will work fine. You can change `public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyArrList.size();
    }` also.